# Morris Chart convert data from string to object

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json, charts

I have this string variable built dynamically:

```
var vData = "[{value: 7, label: '1'},{value: 45, label: '2'},{value: 38, label: '4'},{value: 9, label: '7'}]";
```

How can I convert my string variable into an array to pass the data parameter?

I've tryed in Javascript with: `JSON.parse(vData)`, but don't work.
In a separated PHP file, I've tryed with: `echo json_encode($arr);` at the end of PHP file, but don't work.

Where am I wrong?

Comment: What data parameter?

Comment: Morris.Donut({
 element: 'show-graph',
 data: vData,
 formatter: function (x) { return x + "%"}
}).on('click', function(i, row){
 console.log(i, row);
});

Comment: You'll have to wrap your strings and property names in double quotes for `JSON.parse` to work. E.g.: `'[{"value": 7, "label": "1"}]'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll have to wrap your strings and property names in double quotes for JSON.parse to work. E.g.: `[{"value": 7, "label": "1"}]`

I'd strongly suggest fixing this in your string generation code, but just to show you it works (definitely not the right regex approach):

```js
var data = "[{value: 7, label: '1'},{value: 45, label: '2'},{value: 38, label: '4'},{value: 9, label: '7'}]";


data = data.replace(/value/g, '"value"');
data = data.replace(/label/g, '"label"');
data = data.replace(/\'/g, '"'); 

console.log(JSON.parse(data));
```